# Change Citestyle to give Doe, J. (2013a) instead of Doe, J. (2013)a

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I'm currently searching for a way to adjust the citestyle to fit my university's requirements. Currently I get as footnote `See John, D. (2013)a` when multiple books with same author and year exist. How can I change it, so have the letter inside the brackets?

EDIT: Here the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[citestyle=dhbw_ibim]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\begin{document}
foo\footcite[See][2]{test1}
bar\footcite[See][5]{test2}
\end{document}
```

The citestyle-file is available at: https://github.com/schocco/DHBW-stgt-template/blob/master/src/dhbw_ibim.cbx

The bib used is:

```
@misc{test1,
author = {Doe, John},
year = {2013}
} 

@misc{test2,
author = {Doe, John},
year = {2013}
}
```

Finally, I'm compiling with:

```
pdflatex mini.tex | biber mini | pdflatex mini.tex
```

EDIT2: \listfiles

```
*File List*
scrartcl.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
biblatex.sty    2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
blx-dm.def
dhbw_ibim.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def
standard.bbx    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
numeric.bbx    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
dhbw_ibim.cbx    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)$Id:dhbw_ibim.cbx,v 0.1 2011/06/08 Rocco Schulz $
biblatex.cfg
english.lbx    2013/07/15 v2.7a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
mini.bbl
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There is (and easily, if the `biblatex` tag is correct).  But you haven't given us much to go on.  Please provide a complete but [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  It really helps **you** get the help you need more quickly.

Comment: I've added the minimal example and a link to the citestyle-file I use.

Comment: Running your example on my test bibliography gives the expected output, and an inspection of the `.cbx` file indicates that this is what the the style does.  Perhaps you have an older version of the `.cbx`?

Comment: That's strange, because my `.cbx` is up to date. I've added my testbib and the commands used for compiling.

Comment: You need to run `pdflatex` more than once after running `biber`.  Also, `biber` and `biblatex` seem to be more sensitive to errors in the `.aux` files, so try deleting them and trying again. (You should delete the `.bcf`, `.run.xml`, `.bbl` and `.aux` files.)

Comment: I've deleted all files but the ´.tex,´ ´.bib´ and ´.cbx´. The result is still the same, even after multiple runs of pdflatex after the biber-run: http://abload.de/img/footnotejcf63.png

Comment: Can you put `\listfiles` in your document and add the result to your question?  I'm running TL 2013, and everything works as expected.

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.4757, the output of \listfiles is added.

Comment: I'm stumped, sorry.  Your `biblatex` is slightly older (2.7a vs. my 2.8) but I tried the document with an even older one (2.5 from TL 2012) and still get a good result.

Comment: I've tried it with TexLive2013 and it worked as it should - then  I decided to reinstall MikTeX and was able to reproduce the correct behaviour with it too. Seems like something was messed up. Alan: Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about a software problem solved by an update.